# Why are these vectors linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra

I got it from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence), but why are they dependent?

[image: three vectors in space. One is a multiple of another, while the third has a different direction]

([Image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#/media/File:Vec-dep.png) by Wikimedia user Schnelliboy, cropped.  Used under a Creative Commons license ([CC-BY-SA-4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0))

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Try to not use picture in the question session. Use MathJax formatting for mathematical expressions. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: What is the wikipedia link?

Comment: Is that three vectors, two of which are collinear?

Comment: @nmasanta the picture is a figure, not an image of text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see that two of the vectors are parallel—lying one on top of the other.  Call the shorter one $v_1$ and the longer one $v_2$.  Call the other one $v_3$.

Since $v_2$ and $v_1$ are parallel, there exists a scalar  $\lambda$ such that $v_2 = \lambda v_1$.  From the picture, it appears $\lambda \approx 1.5$.

Let $c_1 = \lambda$, $c_2 = -1$, and $c_3 = 0$.  These three scalars are not all zero.  Yet
$$
   c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + c_3 v_3 = 
   \lambda v_1 - v_2 + \vec 0 = \vec 0
$$
So the three vectors $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ are linearly dependent.